# Do the pirate treasures have any use?

Tags: yooka-laylee

Yooka-Laylee is riddled with collectibles.  However, there is one that is untracked in the Totals menu, which are the [pirate treasures](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Treasure).  From what I've read, there are a total of 5 of them.  [The Wiki](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Treasure) states the use for them is currently unknown.  I've also found [an article](https://www.destructoid.com/yooka-laylee-guide-locations-of-all-five-secret-pirate-treasures-430549.phtml) that discusses them and states that they go towards achievements.

Do the pirate treasures have any other use in the game or are they purely for achievements?

Comment: Seeing as the developers of YL also worked on Banjo-Kazooie, I wouldn't be too surprised to learn that the pirate treasures were similar to BK's "Mystery Eggs" or the "Ice Key" - secrets which are accessible in the game but don't have a clear purpose. Great question though, I'm really curious myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nope**, they just unlock three hidden achievements